# What about idle users and their questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are plenty of questions around for which there have been answers proposed but apparently the poster has never looked back at it (speaking of cases where there are no accepted answers). They merely increase the number of unanswered questions of the site. Anything that can be done?

Should there be a feature like a "community accepted answer" or something? Let us say if 5 or more users (non poster) find the answer as the appropriate one, they could perhaps accept it on behalf of the poster?

Comment: This doesn't actually "increase the number of unanswered questions of the site." As I understand it the statistics count questions as answered if they have answers, regardless of whether any of the answers are accepted.

Comment: @BESW the system counts a question as answered if it has at least one *upvoted* answer (even if not accepted).  0-score answers (and lower) don't count.

Comment: This has come up on MSO and the answer has been "no"; answer acceptance is the purview of the asker and the community can't do that on his behalf.  (That is, feature requests about this have been declined.)  If I find the relevant posts I'll make a real answer, but leaving this breadcrumb for now in case somebody else wants to run with it.

Comment: I'd rather have a "nag button" which a moderator could hit, or the system would generate nag emails after predetermined amounts of time, to remind the asker to accept an answer already.